# How to consume and save a List of custom types in Spring Boot using Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am writing a Kafka producer and consumer to send my custom data and save after consuming. I did all the required Kafka configurations, but I get a casting exception.

These are the codes:

Consumer:

```
public class Consumer {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    @Autowired
    private RecordService service;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "data", groupId = "group_id", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(List<Record> message) {
        logger.info(String.format("$$ -> Consumed Message -> %s", "message"));

        System.out.println(message);
        service.saveAll(message);
    }
}
```

Producer:

```
public class Producer {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
    private static final String TOPIC = "data";
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, List<Record>> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(List<Record> list) {
        logger.info(String.format("$$ -> Producing message --> %s", "message"));
        // Message<List<Record>> message =
        // MessageBuilder.withPayload(list).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC,
        // TOPIC).build();

        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, list);
    }
}
```

KafkaConfig for consumer

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "json");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, List<Record>> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(List.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<Record>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<Record>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

KafkaConfig for producer:

```
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, List<Record>> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, List<Record>> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

The message successfully sent and printed to console, but the type is not what I expect. I send a List, but it is received as a List of LinkedHashMap. There is Stack Trace Error:

```
2019-08-28 17:41:52.612  INFO 22236 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] com.consumerApp.models.Consumer          : $$ -> Consumed Message -> message
[{region=Central America and the Caribbean, country=Haiti, itemType=Office Supplies, salesChannel=Online, orderPriority=C, orderDate=1293739200000, orderId=485070693, shipDate=1296417600000, unitsSold=2052, unitPrice=651.21, unitCost=524.96, totalRevenue=1336282.92, totalCost=1077217.92, totalProfit=259065.0}, {region=Central America and the Caribbean, country=Nicaragua, itemType=Household, salesChannel=Online, orderPriority=C, orderDate=1445976000000, orderId=573998582, shipDate=1449432000000, unitsSold=7791, unitPrice=668.27, unitCost=502.54, totalRevenue=5206491.57, totalCost=3915289.14, totalProfit=1291202.43}]
2019-08-28 17:41:52.613 ERROR 22236 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = data, partition = 0, offset = 16, CreateTime = 1566999712608, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 675, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [{region=Central America and the Caribbean, country=Haiti, itemType=Office Supplies, salesChannel=Online, orderPriority=C, orderDate=1293739200000, orderId=485070693, shipDate=1296417600000, unitsSold=2052, unitPrice=651.21, unitCost=524.96, totalRevenue=1336282.92, totalCost=1077217.92, totalProfit=259065.0}, {region=Central America and the Caribbean, country=Nicaragua, itemType=Household, salesChannel=Online, orderPriority=C, orderDate=1445976000000, orderId=573998582, shipDate=1449432000000, unitsSold=7791, unitPrice=668.27, unitCost=502.54, totalRevenue=5206491.57, totalCost=3915289.14, totalProfit=1291202.43}])

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.consumerApp.models.Consumer.consume(java.util.List<com.consumerApp.models.Record>)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.consumerApp.models.Record; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.consumerApp.models.Record
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1272) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1261) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1188) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1159) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1099) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:934) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:750) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:699) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.consumerApp.models.Record
    at com.consumerApp.models.RecordService.saveAll(RecordService.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.consumerApp.models.Consumer.consume(Consumer.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:283) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:79) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:50) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1224) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1217) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1178) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Why isn't it received as a List? Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you get is `List<LinkedHashMap>`, because your deserializer is `JsonDeserializer<>(List.class)`, its actual target type is `Lis<Object>`, and eventually jackson converts it to `List<LinkedHashMap>`.

```java
String str = "[{\"region\": \"Central America and the Caribbean\", \"country\":\"Haiti\", " +
                "\"itemType\":\"Office Supplies\"}]";
List list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, List.class);
System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass());
```

It print `class java.util.LinkedHashMap`.

As far as i know, you should use a custom deserializer.

```java
static class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<MyRecord>> {

        @Override
        public List<MyRecord> deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
            return deserialize(topic, data);
        }

        @Override
        public List<MyRecord> deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
            if (data == null) {
                return null;
            }
            try {
                return objectMapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<List<MyRecord>>() {
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new SerializationException("Can't deserialize data [" + Arrays.toString(data) +
                        "] from topic [" + topic + "]", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It makes sense. But it is strange, that I can not give my own type in Generics. Perhaps it is possible to define a List<Record> as a new class "SomeNewClass" and then give that as a `new JsonDeserializer<>(SomeNewClass.class)`  to return me the type I want?

Comment: Glad it helps! Java generics were implemented by type erasure, so there is no type `List<Record>`, When serializing/deserializing, we can not get the actual type of element in list.  If you define a class like `class Records extends ArrayList<Record>`,  It would works for the newly produced message, but if you want to read old message, you should create deserializer like  this: `new JsonDeserializer<>(Records.class, false)`.

Comment: I have tried both methods, the one with custom deserializer worked perfectly, so I mark it solved. The other one did not work for me, gave  this error: `If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source` I tried a solution to trust the package, still not worked.